# Algorithm for drawing tiles on screen

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, 2d

I have struggled with this problem for several days now, and I just can't solve the problem myself.

I have a Minecraft 2D sort of game. The Blocks are divided into Chunks of 64 * 64 Blocks.

**I have this draw function:**

```
@Override
protected void gameDraw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(Texture.getImage("background"), 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, null);

    int pixelXMin = (int) (screenX);
    int pixelYMin = (int) (screenY);
    int pixelXMax = (int) (canvas.getWidth() + screenX);
    int pixelYMax = (int) (canvas.getHeight() + screenY);

    int blockXMin = pixelXMin / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH;
    int blockYMin = pixelYMin / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT;
    int blockXMax = pixelXMax / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH;
    int blockYMax = pixelYMax / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT;

    int diffX = pixelXMin % Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH;
    int diffY = pixelYMin % Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT;

    for (int bx = blockXMin; bx < blockXMax; bx++) {
        for (int by = blockYMin; by < blockYMax; by++) {

            int chunkNum = bx / Chunk.COLUMNS_IN_CHUNK;
            int blockX = bx % Chunk.COLUMNS_IN_CHUNK;
            int blockY = by % Chunk.COLUMNS_IN_CHUNK;

            Chunk chunk = level.loadChunk(chunkNum);
            Block block = chunk.getBlock(blockX, blockY);

            if (block == null) { continue; }
            BlockData blockData = block.getBlockData();
            if (blockData.getType().getTextureName().equals("")) { continue; }

            int blockPosX = canvas.getWidth() - (bx * Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH + diffX);
            int blockPosY = canvas.getHeight() - (by * Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT + diffY);

            BufferedImage image = Texture.getImage(blockData.getType().getName());

            g.drawImage(image, blockPosX, blockPosY, Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH, Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here i tried to calculate the maximum and minimum number of pixels on the screen with the variables `screenX` and `screenY` who serve as "camera position". Then I loop through every block that is within these pixels.

The rest is sort of self explanatory.

**Now for the problem:**
[image]
As you can see does the game draw nicely, but when you change the values of `screenX` and `screenY`, the "box" of blocks move realtive to the screen, but the blocks stay at the same location.

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Link to dropbox download for .jar file and full sourcecode. `gameDraw()` is in CubeExplorer.java
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/madienlwmhjt2wh/AADA83aKa00j5UFowhotfmmaa?dl=0

**SOLUTION**
Here is my solution:

```
@Override
protected void gameDraw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(Texture.getImage("background"), 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, null);

    int x = (int) (screenX / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH);
    int y = (int) (screenY / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT); 

    int blockXMin = x;
    int blockYMin = y;

    int blockXMax = x + canvas.getWidth() / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH + 2;
    int blockYMax = y + canvas.getWidth() / Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH + 2;

    System.out.println(x + "," + y + "    " + blockXMax + "," + blockYMax);

    for(int blockX = blockXMin; blockX < blockXMax; blockX++) {
        for(int blockY = blockYMin; blockY < blockYMax; blockY++) {

            int chunkX = blockX / Chunk.COLUMNS_IN_CHUNK;
            Chunk chunk = level.loadChunk(chunkX);

            int blockChunkPosX = blockX % Chunk.COLUMNS_IN_CHUNK;
            int blockChunkPosY = blockY % Chunk.ROWS_IN_CHUNK;
            Block block = chunk.getBlock(blockChunkPosX, blockChunkPosY);

            if (block == null) { continue; }
            BlockData blockData = block.getBlockData();
            if (blockData.getType().getTextureName().equals("")) { continue; }

            int blockScreenLocX = (int) ((int) + blockX * Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH - screenX);
            int blockScreenLocY = 600 - (int) ((int) + blockY * Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT - screenY);

            BufferedImage image = Texture.getImage(blockData.getType().getName());
            g.drawImage(image, blockScreenLocX, blockScreenLocY, Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_WIDTH, Block.BLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT, null);

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the 800 and 600 for? and isnt the '0' in "int pixelXMin = (int) (0 + screenX);"  redundant?

Comment: 800 is screenWidth and 600 is screenHeight. 0, 0 is the top left corner (opposite of right bottom).

Comment: Best not to assume screen sizes, but use actually values determined from the current state of the viewable area

Comment: Okey @MadProgrammer thank you for the tip

Comment: Yes, exactly what i was going to say if the 800/600 was actually screen size.